# Does IE(7?) distort backgrounds from sprites?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-image, sprite

I am pulling my hair out on this one.

We're just about done with the development of an overhaul to our site. As a last step, we're trying to wrap up all the glyphs and icons into a sprite. They're all transparent .png's so the sprite is too. It appears that if a background comes from a sptire, IE distorts it. If it comes from the original file, it does not. FF and Chrome are fine either way.

I am looking at the orignal image and the sprited version side-by-side with grids to see that the pixels are identical. I have counted the pixels in the sprite many times to ensure I'm using the right coordinates. My CSS looks like this:

```
XXbackground: url(sprite.png) no-repeat 0px -837px; /* lozRedRedSpacer */
background: url(lozRedRedSpacer.png) no-repeat;
```

The 'XX' lets me toggle back and forth. With the single-file version, it looks perfect: [image: seperate file background]. The sprite-version looks like this: [image: sprite]. It looks like it is 'squished' both vertically and horizontally. This does not happen in FF or Chrome.

Any ideas?

***EDIT*** I was able to strip out most of the noise and post an example [here](http://stream.insigniagroup.com/temptest/index.htm). I've added notes to the example to describe my problem.

Thank you so much for taking the time to look at this!

***UPDATE*** We've since replaced these 'overlapped divider images' with CSS pseudo-classes that REALLY do overlap and the zooming issue seems to have gone away. Of course now we have new problems - IE8 gets the z-order wrong and IE7 doesn't understand psuedo-elements at all. But at least the markup is simpler and the zooming issue is gone.

Comment: To me, that looks less "squished" and more like a one-pixel offset along both axes.  Having a zero-pixel x-offset doesn't agree with that, but it's probably worth double-checking your sprite math, if you haven't already.

Comment: @Ben: That's a great suggestion and we've been noodling with the numbers. When we move the Y up or down 1px we clearly see a horizontal black line top or bottom we we'd expect from missing the image. In this case the distortion even appears 'sub-pixel' if that's possible!

Comment: Can you get a working example that shows up the problem, somewhere like jsfiddle.net, say? It's odd; it looks like something's adding a bevel effect somehow.

Comment: @Matt: Posted an example. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Hrm. Sorry, but I can't reproduce the problem. The bars are identical for me in IE8, which I can run native, and IE7, which I'm running using IETester. Does this happen on different machines? I don't know whether perhaps IE7 in IETester isn't behaving absolutely exactly as IE7 standalone would, or perhaps there's actually something odd going on in your install of IE7...

Comment: Oh my - I found it! My eyes really suck so I usually run IE at 125% zoom. Turn off zoom, and it looks and acts perfectly!

Comment: Please answer your own question and mark as answered for others in the future with the same problem.

Comment: @ripper234: My 'solution,' lame as it seems, is to NOT zoom in IE7! I am definately the only one in our office who sees this because everyone else sees better and doesn't need to zoom :)

Comment: @n8wrl - well, I'm trying to build a website, I can't tell my users "please don't zoom on IE7-8" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out my problem was caused by IE's 'zoom' feature. Without any zoom, everything looks great like the other browsers. Even 150% or 200% looks good. But 125%, where I had it, causes this distortion. It happens in IE7 and IE8.

Comment: Thanks. I found this same issue on IE 9. I zoomed to 100% and the problem went away.  Why oh why can't Microsoft get it right!  Why don't they just use webkit and give up on making their own browsers and save developers hassles and headaches and make the entire web move forward.